# Group array of object by key - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, reduce

Before anything, I did look for the other answers on the internet but I still can't get it to work and I don't know why

So, I have an array with objects:

```
array =[
   {
      "name":"Alex",
      "id":0
   },
   {
      "age":20,
      "id":0
   },
   {
      "name":"John",
      "id":1
   },
   {
      "age":30,
      "id":1
   }
]
```

I want to group them based on their id so I expect the outcome to be like this:

```
array =[
   [
      {
         "name":"Alex",
         "id":0
      },
      {
         "age":20,
         "id":0
      }
   ],
   [
      {
         "name":"John",
         "id":1
      },
      {
         "age":30,
         "id":1
      }
   ]
]
```

I found a bunch of answer to work with something similar so I gave it a try but I don't know why it is not working

```
 array.reduce((a, value) => {
       a[value.id] = [...a[value.id] || [], value];
        return a;
    }, [])
```

Can someone explain why?

Comment: Take any of the _"group array of objects by property"_ duplicates. They will almost always return an object (`{ "0": [ ... ], "1": [ ... ] }`). Pass this object to `Object.values()` and you should have your expected result.

Comment: The edit you just made makes your code work - although, it currently relies on your ids being valid array indexes which continuously increase from 0

Answer (score 0):

That's because `value.index` is not existed so its value is always `undefined`.

Change `value.index` to `value.id` and it will work as expected.

```js
const array = [{
    "name": "Alex",
    "id": 0
  },
  {
    "age": 20,
    "id": 0
  },
  {
    "name": "John",
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "age": 30,
    "id": 1
  }
];

const output = array.reduce((a, value) => {
  a[value.id] = [...a[value.id] || [], value];
  return a;
}, []);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You used wrong key used - `index`,it should be corrected to `id`

```js
const array = [{
    "name": "Alex",
    "id": 0
  },
  {
    "age": 20,
    "id": 0
  },
  {
    "name": "John",
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "age": 30,
    "id": 1
  }
]

const output = array.reduce((a, value) => {
  a[value.id] = [...a[value.id] || [], value];
  return a;
}, [])

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your particular example, there is no "index" attribute to your objects so when you call `value.index` you will get `undefined`. If you are trying to use the id fields as the index of the final array (which is what I think you are trying in that reduce function), try the below. Please note that if you do not have consecutive ids in your objects starting at 0, then you will have null values inserted into your final array. You can remove these by doing something like `array.filter((el) => el );` to your final array.

```
array.reduce((a, value) => {
  if (a[value.id]) {
    a[value.id].push(value);
  } else {
    a[value.id] = [value];
  }
  return a;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You practically had a typo question and fixed it with the edit, however if you want to make it work with arbitrary ID-s (as a comment points out, `0` and `1` are valid and "early" array indices), you may want to use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), and get its [`values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values) at the end:

```js
const array = [{
    "name": "Alex",
    "id": 80
  },
  {
    "age": 20,
    "id": 80
  },
  {
    "name": "John",
    "id": 100
  },
  {
    "age": 30,
    "id": 100
  }
]

const map = array.reduce((a, value) => {
  a.set(value.id, [...a.get(value.id) || [], value]);
  return a;
}, new Map())
const output = Array.from(map.values());

console.log(output);
```